# How do I complete the "Everyone's A Critic" mission?

Tags: lego-batman-3

Kevin Smith asks me to retrieve his film reel.  I get prompted to switch to sensor suit, and activate it - it creates a trail of coins going up. Catwoman brags about having stolen it, my senses tingle again. I activate the sensor, and it creates a new line of coins, leading... Nowhere. No obvious sensor point or anything else.

Is this mission bugged? (I'm on 360.) Or is there something non-intuitive I have to do here?  If it is bugged, is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - there were more rubbish piles to beat up before the later sensor points would activate.  The second pile is in the corner of the stairwell.

Answer (score 1):

You'll see some trash pop up (pizza boxes and a trash can). Smash it, scan again, go down the ladder, then repeat and follow the trail of studs that leads to more trash cans back where you came from, around by the central platform, and then on the platform to the right of that.
[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/800923-lego-batman-3-beyond-gotham/70589030)

Comment: See, I found that page, which is how I knew I needed to go up the ladder in the first place.  (I may be dumb sometimes.)  But that doesn't do anything to handle the point about not being able to find the third sensor point at all.

Comment: Do you see the trash pile?

Comment: Yes - Catwoman doesn't seem to appear until after you've smashed it up some.

Comment: Then I dont know how to help you. Sorry :(